# Xcode Build Fail - Flutter ios

Tags: ios, flutter, twilio

I'm new to iOS. I'm trying to build a flutter Project which uses [flutter_twilio](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_twilio) package. I'm facing below stated error while I'm trying to run it. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Can anyone guide me to fix this. And When I try to remove that package and run it. it's working absolutely fine. But I cannot change the package at this time.

```
Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_TVOAcceptOptions


Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_TwilioVoice


Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_TVOConnectOptions


Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_TVODefaultAudioDevice
```

And my Podfile is

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to clean all the dependencies and delete `Profile.lock` before XCode build?

Comment: Yes I did but no use

Comment: Did you clean the build cache and then the `$ pod install` again?

Comment: Yes I did But same output